# How to serialize (using protobuf-net) a field that is the object described in another assembly (dll)?

Tags: c#, serialization, dll, protobuf-net

I'm using *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll* in my project. I have a class, the property of this class is an object that had been described in *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll* and connected to my project.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class FunctionAnnotation : 
{
     [ProtoMember(1)] public IMethodSymbol Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

`IMethodSymbol` described in *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll*.

I use protobuf-net.
When you try to serialize an object it throws an exception:

> No serializer defined for type: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMetnodSymbol

It is clear that *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Method.Symbol* is not marked as *[ProtoContract]*

```
  private void Serialization()
    {
         string folderName = @"f:/serialization/";
         Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
         int name = this.Symbol.ToString().GetHashCode();
         using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("f:/serialization/" + name + ".dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
         {
              Serializer.Serialize(fs, this);
         }
    }
```

What are the options for marking of existing classes?
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can manually configure external types using the `RuntimeTypeModel` API, i.e.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SomeTYpe), false).Add("Member", 1); // etc
```

But: this will work best if the external type is a DTO-style object. If it is a complex domain object, you would be better served by introducing a DTO map separately, i.e. a set of objects you control that represents the **data** you need, rather than the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mark. If you don't complicate, could you tell me where you can see how to represent the DTO-style object.

Comment: @G4us I don't know anything about `IMethodSymbol`; it really depends on your system